# 3 white wires and 3 black wires from ceiling fixture

Tags: ceiling-fan

There are 2 switches on the wall.  One controls the fan and the other is for the lights.  Ground wires are connected.  How do I connect the 6 wires to the 3 from the fan?

Comment: We need a bit more information and possibly a photo of the wires , fan type model, brand not all brands have the same color code and we need to know if there are any connections existing in the box.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the fan and switch boxes please?